# Ping requests time out for specific packet sizes

Tags: vpn, ping, mtu

After having VPN problems with my new internet provider on LTE router Huawei B315s-22, found out such interesting behavior:

```
ping bite.lv -f -l 1436 -n 1 -----> Reply from 213.226.139.45: bytes=1436 time=48ms TTL=57
ping bite.lv -f -l 1437 -n 1 -----> Request timed out.
                   ....
ping bite.lv -f -l 1472 -n 1 -----> Request timed out.
ping bite.lv -f -l 1473 -n 1 -----> Packet needs to be fragmented but DF set.
```

Seems for packet size range 1437—1472 ping request always times out.

Changing MTU size on the router to 1400 does not help.

Comment: What was the local VPN endpoint? Your router or some other device? Was the ping you did going through the VPN tunnel or not?

Comment: The ping was done without connecting to VPN. I believe that these MTU size issues were causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what happens when you specify `-f`. There are, unfortunately, a significant number of [MTU black holes](https://www.fir3net.com/Networking/Protocols/path-mtu-path-mtu-black-holes.html) on the Internet. It's usually caused by clueless admins who filter all ICMP because they vaguely recall hearing that it's a threat.

Comment: Worth to mention that the ping fails also without "Do not fragment" flag `-f` for packet with size 1437 and above. Still this may be the same problem with MTU black holes you mentioned.